# Netbeans 11 java BUILD FAILED

Tags: netbeans, build, java

Компилирую проект java web в netbeans 11, JDK-8. В проекте ошибок нет, но не собирается, - BUILD FAILED. Другой подобный проект собирается без проблем. В чем может быть проблема?

```
ant -f /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=/home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org clean dist
init:
undeploy-clean:
deps-clean:
do-clean:
Deleting directory /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build
check-clean:
clean:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
Created dir: /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/META-INF
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/META-INF
Copying 9 files to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
Created dir: /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/empty
Created dir: /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 18 source files to /home/mumu/NetBeansProjects/search_org/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```